# Authorization_RequestDenied getting Group Members with /groups/ID/members

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I must say that I already check on the internet and the similar questions on SO, sadly it didn't solve my issue.

I am trying to get the members of a group using Microsoft Graph, but the call "groups/$groupID'/members" seems not to work and reports this error:

```
array(1) { ["error"]=> array(3) { ["code"]=> string(27) "Authorization_RequestDenied" ["message"]=> string(50) "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." ["innerError"]=> array(2) { ["request-id"]=> string(36) "b77a1174-934a-401a-b589-6e097baa43d4" ["date"]=> string(19) "2020-04-28T14:10:52" } } }
```

I already assigned, according to the documentation, the related permissions (application permissions) as you can see in the picture: [image]

Can anyone help me understand why it does not work? The access token actually works because using "/groups" to get the list of all the groups is okay, it must be a problem with the permissions, but I already included all the required ones.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Lovest, are you facing this issue with the West Europe region? I am also facing this issue only in West Europe region. It is working fine in UK South.

Comment: yes exactly, same region. The weird aspect is that it worked two days ago when I implemented it, but from the day after it stopped

Comment: Yeah same here. All of sudden it stopped working yesterday in West Europe but working perfectly in other regions.

Comment: Hi @Lovest you can remove the permission of `Group.Selected` for the time being and it will start working again as expected.

Comment: @SaurabhSrivastava thank you so much! It worked :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @SaurabhSrivastava the problem was caused by the permission `Group.Selected`

removing that, the API restarted working.